# virtual function not able to display proper result

Tags: c++

I have done C++ program, where my base class i.e. `Shape` does the job of taking data , and the other two derived classes `Triangle` and `Rectangle`  calculate the area . Problem is that I am getting the area as some garbage value. I have done the code, please have a look at it and guide me. Thanks

```
 #include<iostream>
 using namespace std;

  class Shape{
  protected:  double b,h;

   public:void get_data()
      {
        cout<<"Enter the height\n";
        cin>>h;
         cout<<"Enter the breadth\n";
         cin>>b;

         }
   virtual void display_area(){}

  };



  class Rectangle:public Shape
  {
     public:void display_area(){
     cout<<"\n\nArea of Rectangle:" << b*h;
    }
   };

 class Triangle:public Shape
  {

    public:void display_area(){
     cout<<"\n\nArea of Triangle:"<<0.5*b*h; 
     }
 };

  int main()
  {
     Shape s;
     Triangle t;
     Rectangle r;
     Shape *ptr;

     ptr=&s;
     ptr->get_data();

     ptr=&t;
     ptr->display_area();

     ptr=&r;
     ptr->display_area();
     return 0;
 }
```

Answer (score 5):

You called `s.get_data()`, but not `t.get_data`. Therefore `b, h` will be garbage in `t` and `r`.

Comment: is it not possible to  use the getdata function once to get the data nd other clases to use the same data  and calculate and display??

Comment: `t` and `r` are related to the `class Shape`, not the object `s`

Comment: so how am supossed to proceed if i want to use  the getdata function only once?? can you please tell me

Comment: They are different objects. It's like asking why `x=1` doesn't set `y` to 1. They are different variables, different objects.